Custom sequence name strategy in Java Spring Boot and Hibernate 6
Hibernate 6 has the naming strategy for sequences to add a suffix: _SEQ.
How can the suffix be changed from to _SEQ to $SEQ?
I created a custom naming strategy to add the $SEQ suffix so the sequence name would be <entityname>$SEQ.
public class CustomImplicitDatabaseObjectNamingStrategy
    implements ImplicitDatabaseObjectNamingStrategy {
  public static final String STRATEGY_NAME = "custom";

  @Override
  public QualifiedName determineSequenceName(
      Identifier catalogName,
      Identifier shemaName,
      Map<?, ?> configValues,
      ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment = serviceRegistry.getService(JdbcEnvironment.class);

    String entityName = (String) configValues.get("jpa_entity_name");
    String seqName = entityName + "$SEQ";
    System.out.println("seqName " + seqName);

    return new QualifiedSequenceName(
        catalogName, shemaName, jdbcEnvironment.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(seqName, false));
  }

  @Override
  public QualifiedName determineTableName(
      Identifier catalogName,
      Identifier schemaName,
      Map<?, ?> configValues,
      ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

    return null;
  }
}

This custom naming strategy is referenced in the properties with:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy

Hibernate 6 has the default increment step of 50 but my database sequence has only 1. Therefore I tried to change that:
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_entity_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_entity_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "id")
  Long id;

It does not work because quotes are added to the sequence name:
select "MyEntityName$SEQ".nextval

How can I prevent the adding of the quotes? Or is there a better way to change the suffix?
The quotes just make the name case-sensitive. This is a problem, because different databases are used depending on the application properties. Oracle for instance is upper case per default and postgres lower case. But I can not access the properties, since CustomImplicitDatabaseObjectNamingStrategy is not a spring bean and initialised by hibernate.

Can you show a stack trace of your error?

"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet [FEHLER: Relation »StationDevice$seq« existiert nicht\n  Position: 16] [select nextval('"StationDevice$seq"')]; SQL [select nextval('"StationDevice$seq"')]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:277)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible..

Looks like you just didn't create a sequence.

The sequence exists. However, it cannot be found because the quotes make the name of the sequence case sensitive. I can determine the type of database (e.g. Oracle) and capitalize or lowercase the name based on the database type. However, this is not a nice approach. Is there no way to remove the quotes even though there is a special character ($) in the name?

You have to go for custom sequence generator in Hibernate.
Modify to this:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "custom_generator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "custom_generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
       parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_SUFFIX, value = "$seq"),
                @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INITIAL_PARAM, value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1")})
@Column(name = "id")
Long id;

Few points to be noted:

You have to use SequenceStyleGenerator class in Hibernate to customize the sequence generation.

You can change the suffix via this parameter SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_SUFFIX
See if this helps

This does not solve the problem, quotes are still added and therefore the sequence can not be found.
And 'org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator' is deprecated since version 6.5

I think that because of the special character in the sequence name you can't remove the quotes from the query. Hibernate has a setting hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers which, when enabled, forces Hibernate to quote all identifiers. But by default this setting is disabled, and the quotes appear because of the $ character. I suggest you rename your $SEQ suffix to $seq in you determineSequenceName() method, that is, use lowercase. Probably the literals that are quoted are case-sensitive for your database, so the database can't find the sequence.
